# Android Google Services API location returns correct position after X time

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

I am looking to get device's location every 1 minute. I noticed the incorrect location of some devices.

With S7500 the correct location is found after 3-4 minutes sometimes or more, with HUAWEI Y530-U00 the correct location if found instantly. I used the example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates.

S7500 is not very powerful so I thought about a device limitation but it find location after a while. Maybe the code use only phone cell or internet instead of GPS and it makes location difficult.

Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: sounds like a hardware problem to me

Comment: @tyczj I agree with you, I think there isn't a way to solve